# Can I configure Audit.NET to create audit records in two tables on for one audit event?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, audit.net

I am currently implementing [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework) into an ASP.NET Core Web API project that is using EF Core. I am using the [Entity Framework Data Provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework#entity-framework-data-provider) and currently have it configured to map all entities to a single audit log (`AuditLog`) table with the code below.

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
.UseEntityFramework(_ => _
    .AuditTypeMapper(t => typeof(AuditLog))  
    .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((ev, entry, audit) =>
    {
        audit.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
        audit.AuditData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry);
        audit.UserIdentifier = userId;
    })
.IgnoreMatchedProperties(true));
```

This is working great, however, I would like to write audit entries to the `BlogApprovals` table if the entity type is `Blog` - in addition to the entry getting added to `AuditLog`. So for a `Blog` entity I would like an audit record in **both** `BlogApprovals` and `AuditLog`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, since the `EntityFrameworkDataProvider` is designed to map each entity to only one audit entity.

But you could trigger the extra insert, after the operation is complete, by using an `OnSaving` [Custom Action](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-actions), like this:

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.AddOnSavingAction(scope =>
{
    // OnSaving event fires after context SaveChanges 
    var efEvent = (scope.Event as AuditEventEntityFramework)?.EntityFrameworkEvent;
    if (efEvent != null && efEvent.Success)
    {
        foreach (var e in efEvent.Entries)
        {
            if (e.Table == "Blogs" && e.Action == "Insert")
            {
                // there was an insert on blogs table, insert the blogapproval
                var ctx = efEvent.GetDbContext() as MyContext;
                ctx.BlogApproval.Add(new BlogApproval() { Note = "note..." });
                (ctx as IAuditBypass).SaveChangesBypassAudit();
            }
        }
    }
});
```